# pybind11: working with nested py::dict and py::list?

Tags: python, c++, nested, nested-lists, pybind11

Say I have something like this (note `pybind11/pybind11.h and pybind11/stl.h` included)

```
namespace py = pybind11;

int nestedObjSize(py::list plist){
    // This is what I would like to achieve, but it doesn't work

    return plist[0].size()
}

int nestedObjSize(py::dict pdict){
    // Again doesn't work, but this is what I essentially want to do
    
    return pdict["a"].size()
}
```

Now in python

```
bindedModule.nestedObjSize([{"a": 1, "b": 2}])

>> 2

bindedModule.nestedObjSize([[1,2,3]])

>> 3


bindedModule.nestedObjSize({"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2"}})

>> 2
```

The problem stems from the data structure when indexing the `py::list` or `py::dict` is either `py::detail::list_accessor` or `py::detail::item_accessor` respectively, as opposed to just (`py::list` and `py::dict`).

I know that `py::detail::item_accessor` can be declared as a `py::dict` via `py::dict nestDict = rootDict["a"]` assuming the value of `rootDict["a"]` is a `py::dict` (and equivalents for `py::list`) but if the value `rootDict["a"]` is not a `py::dict`, the declaration will result in a `TypeError`

---

So ultimately, the question is, is it possible to access the value of a key or index in `py::dict` or `py::list` respectively, without going through the `..._accessor` intermediates? Or if not is there a way to convert these structures to something that is easier to manipulate in the way I looking to?

Answer (score 1):

Use `py::len()` instead of `size()`:

```py
namespace py = pybind11;

int nestedObjSize(py::list plist)
{
    return py::len(plist[0]);
}

int nestedObjSize(py::dict pdict)
{
    return py::len(pdict["a"]);
}
```